# csvreader.fieldnames not recognized as an attribute of a csv reader object in python

Tags: python, csv, header

I am trying to extract the header of a CSV file in Python by using the CSV module.

The CSV file is quite flat, and looks something like:

> **This, That, The Other**
>
> 1, 2, 3

I am doing the following:

1. Read in the CSV file and make the reader object
2. push the reader's iterator to the next line to force it to access the first line at least once (from the csv module documentation: "If not passed as a parameter when creating the object, this attribute is initialized upon first access or when the first record is read from the file.")
3. assigning the `.fieldnames` attribute to a variable and print it

here is a snippet of code to illustrate:

```
datafile = open(fname, "rb")
reader = csv.reader(datafile) #use csv module to parse in the header
reader.next() # read next line so header will be accessed
rfd_header = reader.fieldnames

print "header:\n"
print rfd_header
```

This results in an error:

> AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'fieldnames'

Which sounds like the `.fieldnames` attribute isn't there, but is in the documentation of Python 2.6.6 (same version of python I am using)

I would appreciate any insight into this mystery. If there is an alternative method to extract the header that would be awesome too!

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you truly want to use csv.reader instead of csv.DictReader, all you need to do is replace

```
reader.next() # read next line so header will be accessed
rfd_header = reader.fieldnames
```

by

```
rfd_header = reader.next()
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked really well.  I can see why DictReader is probably a better method to use, but for my application I need a list.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I then get `'_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'next'` (Python 3)

Answer (score 6):

Try `csv.DictReader` instead of `csv.reader`. The documentation says it too:

*DictReader objects have the following public attribute:*

*csvreader.fieldnames - If not passed as a parameter when creating the object, this attribute is initialized upon first access or when the first record is read from the file.*

http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: You are quite right, I must have misread the documentation :P  I would use DictReader but it just so happens that I need a list.  Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: Uhm what is "this attribute is initialized upon first access" supposed to mean?
To me this sounds like the class will do lazy initialization of the fieldnames any time it needs too.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the result in a list, you could take:

```
rfd_header = reader.next()
```

This should store the first row (header/fields) to the variable "rfd_header"

Then you could iterate over the variable's values and put into a list

```
headerList = []
for item in rfd_header:
    headerList.append(item)
```

Then you can print the result

```
print headerList
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>Apropos of 'rfd_header = reader.next' above, I got this error message in IDLE 3.8.3
>File "<pyshell#2>", line 16, in read_csv_fieldnames
>   fieldnames = csvreader.next()
>AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'next'
>I fixed it by reading the docco on 'Python.org - CSV File Reading and Writing' 
>Under the subheading 'Reader Objects' on the last line of page 6 it says;
>...Usually you should call this as next(reader)
>1-0 for the Python 'docco'
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer